# How to replace the array of values in one dictionary with elements from another array of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my dictionaries:

```
main_dict = [
     {'link_value':[123,111] , 'id' : 22},
     {'link_value':[234] , 'id' : 14}
]
dict2 = [
     {'id':123 , value:['xx','yy'],name:'mg1'},
     {'id':111 , value:['zz','yy'],name:'mg2'},
     {'id':234 , value:['aa','yy'],name:'mg3'}
]
```

I want to replace the link_value with elements from the dict2 array

expected_result:

```
[
     {'link_value':[{'id':123 , value:['xx','yy'],name:'mg1'} ,{'id':111 , value:['zz','yy'],name:'mg2'}] , 'id' : 22},
     {'link_value':[{'id':234 , value:['aa','yy'],name:'mg3'}] , 'id' : 14}
]
```

Comment: you have 2 dictionaries in `main_dict` and 3 in `dict2`, what are the rules for mixing?

Comment: It would be much easier if `dict2` were a dictionary whose keys are the `id` values.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but if you write your own code and have problems, you're welcome to ask here. Please read [ask]. As well, your data has two syntax errors and two name errors.

Comment: I am basically looking at the link_value in my first  array and searching for it in the second array of dicts using id as the identifier and then replacing the key with the dictionary from dict2 itself.

Comment: You just need to write nested loops. Loop through the link values, and then search `dict2` for the dictionary with the matching ID. When you find it, append it to the new value of `link_value`.

Comment: I have tried it using the normal looping approach , which I am thinking is not the best solution and hence I have posted this.

Comment: If you change `dict2` to from a dictionary to a list, you could write that as a list comprehension. It's harder with a list of dictionaries.

Comment: With the data as you've given, the normal looping approach is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Loop across dict1 values for link_value and iterate across list and compare it with id, if it matches append the matched values of dict1 with dict2

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
for i in range(len(main_dict)):
    main_dict[i]['link_value'] = [dict for dict in dict2 if dict['id'] in main_dict[i]['link_value']]
    # main_dict[i]['link_value'] = list(filter(lambda a: a['id'] in main_dict[i]['link_value'], dict2))
```